# How to map any object of [k: string]: any to a generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that return an Output generic type.
This function makes an API call that returns a json object.
I want my function to return this json mapped to its Output Generic type

Here is an example:

```
function myFunc<Output>(): Promise<Output> {
  const apiRes: {[Key: string]: string} = getFromAPI()

  return apiRes as Output
}
```

When I try this, typescript complain about the types not being similar enough, which is not surprising.
I guess the best approach would be to create a function that maps every property of apiRes to those of Output but I have no idea how to get the attributes and values types of a Generic Type

Comment: Do the conversion in JS, then add in the types later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "take responsibility" for the type returned by getFromAPI(), simply so something like this:

```
return getFromAPI()
   .then(res => res as unknown as Output);
```

I'm not sure if it's what you expect?

Comment: Well that could work as I have control over the API and its returned type.
I will take this for the moment. Thank you !